# Is there a database of plots that have not been "processed"/used yet?

Tags: plot

I ask about something coming from my personality.

I have imagination for overall story plots. I don't have a writers' abilities (nor do I have time to write).

I hope there are much more people like me, and that they'd like to see some of their thought up plots to be actually taken by a skillful writer and "converted" to a real book or novel (if the writer considers the plot worth a try).

I've searched a bit on the internet if there is a platform for sharing such ideas and connecting people like me with writers. Haven't found anything. Do you know of such a service?

Thanks for replies / comments.

Comment: Ideas are cheap. https://www.google.com/search?q=ideas+are+cheap Everyone and their grandmother are dreaming up ideas. No one needs your ideas. What everyone wants is the skill to write, draw or film *their own* ideas.

Comment: That sounds like a good starting point for a plot!

Answer (score 2):

It's been done in at least a few books:

1. [20 Master Plots: And How To Build Them by Tobias](http://newtonsaber.com/AmazonBooks/BookLink.aspx?author=tobias) - amazon link
2. [Plots Unlimited](http://newtonsaber.com/AmazonBooks/BookLink.aspx?author=sawyer) (A Creative Source for Generating a Virtually Limitless Number and Variety of Story Plots and Outlines)  by Sawyer & Weingarten - amazon link
3. [The Writer's Idea Thesaurus by White](http://newtonsaber.com/AmazonBooks/BookLink.aspx?author=white) - amazon link

and finally, one of the most terrible implementations of the idea is

4. [The Amazing Story Generator by Sacher](http://newtonsaber.com/AmazonBooks/BookLink.aspx?author=sacher) - amazon link

Those will give you a good idea of how this concept has been done numerous times before.

Comment: Thanks, but books are not a "live" medium, where users could discuss, inspire each other, tag and search through the ideas... Having an inspiration for general plot twists might be useful, but what am I talking about is a database of specific plots (like an interesting combination of a specific environment/conditions). I mainly think in sci-fi terms, so maybe this just isn't useful everywhere, but who knows...

Comment: Sure, it sounds like an interesting idea to me.  Shouldn't be difficult to do, just might take some time.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your support ;) If I manage to find time to launch such service, I'll report here :)

Comment: @peci1: How about a service that helps rescue stories/novels where authors have written themselves into a corner?  That should be popular!  :-D